# What is considered Greener/Greenest laminate flooring option available?

Tags: hardwood-floor, adhesive, laminate-floor, green

After doing extensive research on hardwood flooring, I have resigned myself to laminate due to an aging dog who has increasingly suspect bladder control.

Given that laminate is completely artificial I am concerned about the binding agents used. I want to get a VOC & Urea Formaldehyde flooring but it seems this information is hard to locate when compared to the woods.

Can someone throw out some greener options? I want a green product and fake the look of wood until we are pet free and can invest in a nicer floor. This would be an above grade installation over concrete and I am looking for click lock products.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked into strand woven bamboo click lock flooring? Nice looking (especially the carbonised variant) and hard wearing. More expensive than laminate IIRC but cheaper than hardwood

Comment: You ought to be clearer about what you mean by "green".  It can mean no old-growth trees were killed, or it can mean greenhouse gases were kept to a minimum, or it can mean LEED certification, stuff like that.  Which aspect of "green" are you concerned with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my last kitchen remodel, I used [linoleum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linoleum), mostly because it was a natural and "green" product. Note that vinyl flooring is often inappropriately called linoleum. You can read more online, but I thought it looked great, was easy to install and care for, and supposedly lasts a very long time.

Here is a Georgia Tech labelled paper that discusses the different choices, rating them on environmental impact and other factors.

> Linoleum is made from all natural ingredients. Linseed oil is derived by pressing flaxseed and it is dried and ground into a powdery binder. This is combined with limestone, which is extremely abundant, pine rosin, and cork and wood flours to form a doughy material to which color is added. Once pressed, it is rolled onto a jute backing and dried. Jute is
>   spun from fibers of jute plants grown in India and Bangladesh (Forbo Industries).

[Resilient Flooring: A Comparison of Vinyl, Linoleum and Cork](https://www.pharosproject.net/uploads/files/sources/2135/1335146026.pdf)

Edit: I just reread your question more carefully, and see that you're specifically looking for click-lock products. Forbo makes a product like that, [Marmoleum click tiles](http://www.forbo.com/flooring/en-gl/products/linoleum/marmoleum-click-tiles/bi8kd9) which is their brand of linoleum "Marmoleum" applied on top of an HDF and cork backer. Note that my comments about linoleum apply to the linoleum material and jute backing. I don't know what glues or other materials are used in that specific product. I used glued-down tiles.

Comment: Awesome, do you have pets have the floors held up well with that abuse?

Comment: I had a dog, which was another reason for choosing this. Note that the color layer is solid, so it isn't like PVC flooring that claws can scratch through the wear layer.